# Cannot deploy to AVD (I'm using Android Studio on Mac)

Tags: android, macos, deployment, android-virtual-device

When I click run, the AVD boots OK and everything loads, but there's no trace of my app on it; It just shows the android home screen, and my app is not in the applications list.

And this is the message I get on my "app" log tab:

```
Waiting for device.
/Volumes/iSpace/Radium/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator -avd LG_L40 -netspeed full -netdelay none
```

But my app deploys and runs ok on a real device connected via USB.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried modifying your Run Configurations?
If not, try this:

Run -> Edit Configurations...

Then, select your application, and, inside the Target Device menu, select "Emulator" or "Show chooser dialog". After that, apply and run again.

[image]